# aws cognito not sending verified devices for 2 factor authentication while logging in

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

So I have 2 factor authentication enabled in my aws cognito for my angular app ,the whole logging in is working fine and 2fa also ,but the problem is when I am using trust this device ,its not remembering the device while I am logging in again  ,I can see my device being saved in the trusted device .

Problem -I am not getting any key that says this device is trusted while I am logging in ,so I am unable to identify the trusted device ,following is the data I recieve while logging in

```
{
  "username": "cfae9c26-0adf-43a0-8958-23c6c80f709bqwwee",
  "pool": {
    "userPoolId": "us-west-2_oe4tWrrrl0cl",
    "clientId": "90000",
    "client": {
      "endpoint": "https://cognito-idp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/",
      "fetchOptions": {}
    },
    "advancedSecurityDataCollectionFlag": true,
    "storage": {}
  },
  "Session": "qwwww",
  "client": {
    "endpoint": "https://cognito-idp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/",
    "fetchOptions": {}
  },
  "signInUserSession": null,
  "authenticationFlowType": "USER_SRP_AUTH",
  "storage": {},
  "keyPrefix": "",
  "userDataKey": "",
  "challengeName": "SMS_MFA",
  "challengeParam": {
    "CODE_DELIVERY_DELIVERY_MEDIUM": "SMS",
    "CODE_DELIVERY_DESTINATION": "+********2908"
  }
}
```

Comment: cognito keeps the devicekey stored in local storage ,and when you login again that device key is used to identify if the agent is trusted

Answer (score 2):

In the absence of a few details, I'm making the following assumptions

- You are using `"aws-amplify": "^3.3.26"`.
- `SRP` flow is enabled for the App Client in `Cognito UserPool`.
  [image]
- You allow user to opt-in to remember devices and MFA needs to be suppressed on remembered devices i.e. the `Devices` configuration of the `Cognito UserPool` looks like the following

[image]

If you select `Always` and `Yes` for the Devices configuration, then it won't prompt users for OTP from a remembered device. If you always want MFA even for remembered devices, set the value to `No` in the
`Devices` configuration of the `UserPool`.

In case you want to allow users to opt-in to remember devices and don't want to send SMS on a remembered device, then ensure the following

- Cognito auth flow is set to `authenticationFlowType: 'USER_SRP_AUTH'` (in the config object you pass to `Amplify.configure(config)`)
- When a user opts-in to remember device, you need to invoke the following code

  ```
  async rememberDevice() {
     const user = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
     user.getCachedDeviceKeyAndPassword(); 
     user.setDeviceStatusRemembered({
        onSuccess: (result: any) => {
           //let the user know the operation is successful
        },
        onFailure: (err: any) => {
           console.error(err);
           //let the user know the operation failed
        }
     });
  }
  ```

With that in place, verify that the devices not only appear against the users, but they are remembered as well. In the following image, the device appears against a user, but it is not remembered.

[image]

Cognito stores the device related data and the random password key for SRP flow in `LocalStorage`. For any reason, if those information are missing, the next time the user signs in, then the user would be presented with the configured auth challenge (in this case an OTP sent via SMS).

[image]

In case you need to access the `deviceKey` for a user, you can do so with the following code

```
const user = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
user.getCachedDeviceKeyAndPassword(); 
const deviceKey = user.deviceKey;
```